# Что значит фраза "не издевайся на домной"

Tags: перевод

Я не смог найти перевод в интернете "не издевайся на домной".

Спасибо!

Comment: Just for fun: if were written "не издевайся на**д** домной" that meant "don't mock at a blast furnace".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have the last two words divided in a wrong way. Actually, it is "не издевайся надо мной" meaning "don't mock at me", "don't humiliate me."